# how to store an ArrayList of objects in phone memory and keep its value when end the app?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, gson

Hello Android developer,,
I'm trying to store an ArrayList of objects in a small memory (TinyDB ) in android when I search for I found this object called [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) which supposed to enabled me to save and retrieve my list .
here is my method save :

```
public void save(View view) {
    ArrayList<FoodModel> savedList = new ArrayList<FoodModel>();
    FoodModel foodModel = new FoodModel();

    foodModel.setFoodName(FoodName);
    foodModel.setDate(Date); // date of article
    foodModel.setFoodLink(FoodLink); // link
    foodModel.setImageLink(mainImageUrl);

    savedList.add(foodModel);

    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(DetailActivity.this);
    tinydb.putListObject("SavedList", savedList);

    ArrayList<FoodModel> List = tinydb.getListObject("SavedList" , DetailActivity.class) ;
   // Log.i(TAG, "**************************" + tinydb.getListObject("SavedList" , DetailActivity.class).get(0).getFoodName());

}
```

and here is the used methods in TinyDB class :

```
 public ArrayList<Object> getListObject(String key, Class<?> mClass){
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ArrayList<String> objStrings = getListString(key);
    ArrayList<Object> objects =  new ArrayList<Object>();

    for(String jObjString : objStrings){
        Object value  = gson.fromJson(jObjString,  mClass);
        objects.add(value);
    }
    return objects;
}

public void putListObject(String key, ArrayList<FoodModel> objArray){
    checkForNullKey(key);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> objStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Object obj : objArray){
        objStrings.add(gson.toJson(obj));
    }
    putListString(key, objStrings);
}
public void putListString(String key, ArrayList<String> stringList) {
    checkForNullKey(key);
    String[] myStringList = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
    preferences.edit().putString(key, TextUtils.join("‚‗‚", myStringList)).apply();
}
```

the error appears when I retrieve the list , I think that it is a cast issue because the method getListObject returns array list of type Object but I couldent fix this ! 
please help :(

Comment: No wonder that it returns an `ArrayList<Object>`if the return parameter says so. You would have to cast the `Objects` to `FoodModels`

Comment: I tried to cast  Objects to FoodModels but the app crashes and get out of Activity :(